# Speeding Through Data on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I have for you what I hope is an interesting question/problem.

I am trying to "replay" a data set on a variable speed. First, look at this code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

#Replay Time Speed
s=10;

#Total Sample Time Array in Tenths of a Second
t=[]
for tenths in np.arange(0, 50.1, 0.1):
    t.append(tenths)

#Time of Events (last element is just to stop loop)
eventsTime=[5.4, 10.0, 37.8, 40.5, 49.2, 50.1]

#Data Replay
eventIndex = 0
for tenths in t:
    if tenths >= eventsTime[eventIndex]:
        print(f"{round(tenths ,2)} - Event!")
        if eventIndex < len(eventsTime)-1:
            eventIndex = eventIndex + 1
    else:
        print(round(tenths,2))
    time.sleep(0.1/s)
```

By changing variable **s** I can print out faster or slower the time array elements. It's fairly neat.

However, I am trying to expand this to Tkinter, and I am not sure if it is even possible. Here is my attempt. You'll find the same loop of above embedded into the object at the function Update(), currently it breaks Python. I've dared to try using time.sleep() but didn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class sensorMenu:
    def __init__(self, controlMenu, timeArray, enventsTimeArray, speed):
        #Tkinter
        self.controlGUI = controlMenu
        self.controlGUI.title('Control')
        self.controlGUI.geometry("300x100")

        #Inputs
        self.timeAarray = timeArray
        self.enventsTimeArray = enventsTimeArray
        self.replaySpeed = round(0.1/speed)

        #Layout
        self.t1 = Label(self.controlGUI, text="Data Replay", font=("lucida 11 bold"))
        self.play = Button(self.controlGUI, text="Play", command=lambda:[self.Start(), self.Update()])
        self.t1.pack()
        self.play.pack()

    def Start(self):
        #Visual
        self.replay= Toplevel()
        self.replay.title('Data Time')
        self.c = Canvas(self.replay, width=200, height=200)
        self.c.configure(bg='grey', highlightthickness=0)

        #Timer
        self.format = (f"Calibri  {str(int(15))}  bold")
        self.replayTimeProgress = (f" 0.0 / {str(self.timeAarray[-1])} ")
        self.timer = self.c.create_text(80, 100, text=self.replayTimeProgress, fill="black", font=("lucida 11 bold"))
        self.eventIndex = 0
        self.c.pack()

    def Update(self):
        #HOW?
        for tenths in self.timeAarray:
            if tenths  >= self.enventsTimeArray[self.eventIndex]:
                self.c.itemconfigure(self.timer, text="EVENT", fill="red")
                if self.eventIndex < len(self.enventsTimeArray)-1:
                    self.eventIndex = self.eventIndex + 1
            self.replayTimeProgress = (f" {str(tenths)} / {str(self.timeAarray[-1])} ")
            self.c.itemconfigure(self.timer, text=self.replayTimeProgress, fill="red")
            self.replay.after(1, self.Update)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t=[]
    for tenths in np.arange(0, 50.1, 0.1):
        t.append(tenths)

    eventsTime=[5.4, 10.0, 37.8, 40.5, 49.2, 50.1]
    s=10;
    controlMenu = Tk()
    expData=sensorMenu(controlMenu, t, eventsTime, s)
    controlMenu.mainloop()
```

What do you think?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: With tkinter, you must use `self.after` to request a callback after a certain number of milliseconds.  Remember, as long as you are in a callback, no drawing gets done.  The drawing is done when you return, and the mainloop can dispatch pending messages.  YOU are not in charge, tkinter is in charge, and you must ask it to call you.

Comment: What does "it breaks" python mean?

Comment: Breaks python as in I will get a Windows message saying "Python is not responding" and the options of closing the program or let it wait to respond.

Comment: Your `after` call is happening every millisecond.

Comment: It's being called far more than a thousand times a second. It's being called one thousand times  the number of items in self.timeArray per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `.after()` is not the same as `sleep()`, it is a *scheduler*. So you should not call `.after()` in a for loop.  Also it is better not using loop in a tkinter main thread as it will block the tkinter `.mainloop()`.

Note also that the first argument of `.after()` is in *milliseconds*.

Below is the required changes to fix the freezing issue:

```py
class sensorMenu:
    def __init__(self, controlMenu, timeArray, enventsTimeArray, speed):
        ...
        self.replaySpeed = speed  # instead of round(0.1/speed)
        ...

    ...

    def Update(self, i=0):
        # don't use for loop
        if i < len(self.timeAarray):
            tenths = self.timeAarray[i]
            if tenths  >= self.enventsTimeArray[self.eventIndex]:
                self.c.itemconfigure(self.timer, text="EVENT", fill="red")
                if self.eventIndex < len(self.enventsTimeArray)-1:
                    self.eventIndex = self.eventIndex + 1
            self.replayTimeProgress = (f" {tenths:.1f} / {self.timeAarray[-1]} ")
            self.c.itemconfigure(self.timer, text=self.replayTimeProgress, fill="red")
            self.replay.after(self.replaySpeed, self.Update, i+1)
```